# Issue with image in GitHub pages, but it works locally

Tags: html, image, github

I have a GitHub pages site I'm working on, and one one page, the image won't display. It works fine when I load the page locally.

Here's the site where it won't load - http://ibldynamics.com/exercises/ex10_36.html
And the code I have is

```
   <div>    
    <h1>Chapter 10, Explorations 36-40</h1>
    <p> Print out the figure below to assist with these explorations. This is Figure 10.1 in your textbook.
    <img src="../images/Sarkpic1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Sarkpic1"></p>

</div>
```

I have another page with an image, and it work's fine - http://ibldynamics.com/exercises/fig6_3.html

And the code I'm using there is

```
   <div>    
    <h1>Chapter 6, Figure 6.3</h1>
    <p> Print out the image below, and use it to assist with explorations 43-47 in the text.
    <img src="../images/logisticPic2.png" class="img-fluid" alt="logisticPic2"> </p>

</div>
```

All preamble stuff was copied and pasted, it's all identical. Any ideas? I've tried multiple browsers, so that's not it.

Comment: There is no image found at the relative path. Are you sure the image is uploaded properly?

Comment: `http://ibldynamics.com/images/Sarkpic1.png` is missing

Comment: wrong path to your image, try to open image path in browser 1st to make sure of it's path then check back your code, u'll find the typo.

Comment: That's the weird bit, it did open in browser, from the local path. I figured it out, the file is called SarkPic1.png, and I had Sarkpic1.png. The local copy didn't care about the capitalization. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image(../images/Sarkpic1.png) is not uploaded on Github Repository. You can see it if you go to this URL http://ibldynamics.com/images/Sarkpic1.png.

The image(../images/logisticPic2.png) is uploaded on Github. To see it, go to this URL http://ibldynamics.com/images/logisticPic2.png.

To fix this,  look/check for image(../images/Sarkpic1.png) into the GitHub repo. if it's not there, then upload it.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be a capitalization problem. No idea why that wasn't an issue in the local version, but got it fixed now, thanks!